# How to free up disk space when the disk is full?

Tags: disk-usage, out-of-memory

I recently tried to install a large program and inadvertently filled up my Linux partition.  I am now seeing a bunch of errors stemming from this issue.  I tried to empty the trash, but I get an error whenever I do so.  I've also done `rm` on several big files, but my OS still seems to think its partition is full, and I'm still seeing the same errors.

**How can I free up some memory so my system starts behaving normally again?**

I'm operating with Linux Mint 18.2.

**Edit:** Some specific errors are as follows:

- When I try to tab-complete in a terminal, I get

  ```
    bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device
  ```
- When I try to manually delete files from the trash folder (via a file browser), I get an alert saying

  ```
  Error while deleting.  There was an error deleting <filename>.
  ```
- When I click the "Empty Trash" button from the file browser, nothing happens.  The files in the Trash are unaffected.

Comment: Try to include some of the errors. That actually tells us what is going on and how it can be fixed. Actual errors are a lot more useful than "a bunch of errors", "I get an error", ...

Comment: @EduardoTrápani I've added some examples.  I'll try to identify some more.  The first one makes it very clear that the system thinks it is out of memory.

Comment: Have you rebooted? That would clear up RAM and `/tmp`.

Comment: You should be able to `cd` into the folder where the Trash is and `rm` them.

Comment: 1) Execute df -h and check output. 2) Files could be removed, but inodes are opened. You can use command lsof to check whether files that were removed still exist.

Answer (score 0):

Rebooting fixed the issue.  I was worried that if the bootloader needed some disk space I might not be able to reboot, so I was saving this as a last resort.  However, it worked.  Note that this was after deleting some files manually via `rm`.